# Positive definite matrix with special coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let ${a_1,...,a_m}$ be a set of linearly independent functions in$L^2(\Omega)$ and let $( . , . )$ the usual defined inner product.

Why is the matrix ${(a_i,a_j)}^m_{i,j=1}$ positive definite?

Any hint please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} ; x\neq 0$
$$x^TAx =\sum_{i,j}x_iA_{ij}x_j =\sum_{i,j}x_i \langle a_i, a_j\rangle x_j$$

Now you can use properties of the inner product.  Linearity in the first term allows simplification to $\sum_j \langle \sum_i x_i a_i, a_j \rangle x_j$, and then linearity in the second term allows simplification to $\langle \sum_i x_i a_i, \sum_j x_j a_j \rangle = \langle y, y \rangle$ for some $y$, and $\langle y, y \rangle$ realizes zero iff $y$ is $0$.  But if $x$ is nonzero, then as $ai$ are linearly independent implies that $y$ is nonzero, in which case $\langle y, y, \rangle$ is strictly greater than $0$.

Putting it together you get that $$x \not= 0 \implies x^TAx > 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $A:L^2 \to \Bbb C^m$ defined by
$$
Af = ((a_1,f),(a_2,f),\dots,(a_n,f))
$$
Verify that $A$ is injective and that $AA^*$ is the linear map whose matrix is $(a_i,a_j)_{i,j = 1}^m$

Comment: Is $A^*$ the adjoint of A , and from these,is there a theorem to directly deduce that A is positive definite?

Comment: Yes and yes.  You should be able to find a suitable theorem in your textbook.

Comment: I am not using a text book, I working on Galerkin method, can you please state the theorem or give me a link ?

Comment: Well here's a link: your matrix is a [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), and it suffices to note that the Gramian matrix of a linearly independent set of vectors will be positive definite.

Comment: is the proof of A injective trivial or I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry!  $A$ is not injective; it's $A^*$ which is injective.  The key here I suppose is that $A$ is surjective.

Comment: Notably, you should find that $A^*$ is the map
$$
A^*:(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto \sum_i x_i a_i
$$

Comment: Also, see my latest edit: our map is $AA^*$, not $A^*A$.